# JPA Update element of ElementCollection

Tags: hibernate, jpa

How to update an element of ElementCollection by JPQL query without merge the host entity?

```
@Embeddable
public class Category {
    @Column(nullable=false)
    String name;

    @Parent
    Item item;
}

@Entity
public class Item {
   @ElementCollection
   Set<Category> categories;
}
```

Is it possible to rename Category without merging an Item? Something like this

```
entityManager.createQuery("update Category c set c.name=:name where c.item = :item")
```

And one more question: in which cases is needed to replace the entity by a merged instance? Is it only when the entity contains collections or other relationships, so contains the proxies?

Comment: since a Category doesn't exist in its own table then clearly you cannot do that. A `merge` is what you do, since a Category only exists in the context of its owner object

Answer (score 0):

Under some circumstances you could use a native query to update the categories like this (assumably the collection table name is `item_categories`):

```
UPDATE {h-schema}item_categories SET name=:name WHERE item_id = :itemId
```

But I'm in doubt that this would be possible or this makes sense at all. Everything depends on how your schema is created.

If you let Hibernate generate your schema (what is NOT recommended), and keep using `@Column(nullable=false)` for the Category name column and a `Set` for your `@ElementCollection` it won't be possible, because Hibernate generates following PK / UNIQUE constraint (for example on PostgreSQL):

```
CREATE TABLE public.item_categories
(
 item_id bigint NOT NULL,
 name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT item_categories_pkey PRIMARY KEY (item_id, name),
 CONSTRAINT fkjfe6s3h4bfur817d80v7aori8 FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
  REFERENCES public.item (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

**Possible adjustments for generated schema:**

With autogenerated schema, you can avoid creation of that constraint by either not using `@Column(nullable=false)` for the Category name column or using a `List` for your `@ElementCollection`.

**Possible adjustments for manually created schema:**

If you created your schema manually (what is recommended) just take care that there is no composite PK / UNIQUE constraint on both columns of the collection table `(item_id, name)`. Otherwise it won't be possible to update that combination.

But again, maybe applying this changes / updating ALL category names is not useful. Do you really want to have the same name on all categories for a single item? How are `equals()` and `hashCode()` implemented on the Category class? Maybe your Set contains only one category per Item after that operation.